# Can I do a diff in git after doing a remote pull?

Tags: git, github

I have two repos: `repo` and `repo-develop`

`repo` is meant for production and has a small team on it that can do pushes and pulls

`repo-develop` is meant for sandbox and anyone can push or pull.

We want it so that no commits can make it from `repo-develop` to `repo` without someone from the production repository reviewing.

It used to be one repository with two branches, but that meant if people were actively developing in their sandbox, they would need to a pull request from their fork for every commit they wanted to get into everyone's local sandbox before going to production.

From my new `repo` I added a remote to `repo-develop`. If I manually pull from there and then do `git status` it says `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.` At this point there's no way for me to diff the codebase ( yet if I push it definitely changes on github )

Is there a way to do this? For all I know I could be doing something crazy from the start and would appreciate a solution that gets my two goals done:

1. Allow all devs to continually push to a branch that can't get into production
2. Have a layer of code review before commits get to production branch/repo

It would have been ideal to fork on github within same user, but it only lets me fork to different users as far as I can tell.

**UPDATE**

I realize that remote pull is bringing over the commit rather than the files. Is there a way around that?

I really would prefer to do a fork of organization/repo to organization/repo-develop but can't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downloaded both repos to my local machine. I update the `develop` one to get all the developers changes. I then use a diff tool on my computer to compare both repos. If everything looks good I do the git pull remote and push it up to origin.

This makes it impossible for 10+ devs to get code into production without review first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git fetch` to only download the changes.
The command `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`. Please have a look at the [documentation of git pull](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html).

Comment: When I do fetch, no files are coming down from remote. `git fetch develop master` is doing nothing, where `develop` is my remote name. I double checked and see there is an update to my develop repo but it won't bring it down.

Comment: Did you check the `git config -e` if the path for `develop` points to the right repository?

Comment: yeah it was to the right one or pull wouldn't work, I would think. Anyway I double checked the config and see that it points to the right repo of -develop